# Is having these 8 citizenships possible?

Tags: citizenship, passport, multiple-citizenship

Currently I'm living in Germany and I only have Polish citizenship and thus a Polish passport. I read that you need to remain in Germany at least 8 years in order to apply for the German citizenship. So I'm going to apply for it in 2 years. I don't think having German and Polish citizenship would be a problem, right?

Just theoretically speaking, would a combination of Polish, German, American, Japanese, Singaporean, South Korean, Israeli and Swiss citizenships (and passports) be possible? Would any of these countries be problematic for a multiple citizenship?

Comment: Note that Germany usually only allows dual citizenship naturalisations from citizens of other EU countries (which will be interesting once for example the UK leaves the EU), otherwise you have to renounce the other

Comment: Well, I am Polish so it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: But after that the others might be more problematic

Comment: The US has virtually no restriction on multiple nationality.  Japan has restrictions.  I don't know about the others.

Comment: Japanese will present some big problems. You will certainly have to renounce all other citizenships, including Polish, to obtain that. That's even if you've got familial connection. South Korea is a bit on the restrictive side as well. Are you Jewish? Because Israel has become a lot more picky about who they confer citizenship to over the last decade or so, but mulitple citizenship is not a problem there (indeed I think it's the norm).Germany will allow dual (mulitple) citizenship for non-EU's if you were born with that citizenship, otherwise no chance. You'd have to renounce all others.

Comment: As soon as you apply for any other citizenship you will automatically lose the German one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japan, Korea and Singapore do not allow dual citizenship. You would have to abandon other citizenships in order to get one of these.